# Exclude a single record from DNSSEC - is it possible?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dnssec

In a domain running DNSSEC, is it possible to exclude a single record from DNSSEC? For example, would it be possible to have `mail.example.com` running DNSSEC, but `www.example.com` not running DNSSEC? The reason for asking is we have a webhosting provider who has issues setting up SSL/TLS for a site because we have DNSSEC running on the DNS for our zone?

I can't see a way to do this in the Bind documentation, but is there some other way?

Comment: Quantim answer is right but DNSSEC is already complicated by itself and full of traps, so I really recommend to just either do fully DNSSEC correctly or no DNSSEC at all, as any "partial"  solution will only bring you more troubles. I am not sure to understand the "ho has issues setting up SSL/TLS for a site because we have DNSSEC running on the DNS for our zone" I do not see the relationship between the two and I think this is your real problem to solve instead of trying to play with DNSSEC setup in a way it was not planned to be done.

Answer (score 4):

Theoreticaly this can be done by creating unsigned subzone for given name but **don't do it** Much better way is change webhosting provider, because yours is incompetent. If DNSSEC brokes their SSL/TLS settings, they do some ugly magic with DNS and this is nothing which you want in your zone.